# Facebook login sdk privacy policy error , the url is not accepted

Tags: facebook

I am using facebook login sdk in my app, It was working fine, then they send me a mail that my privacy policy url is not working, but the url is working!
can someone helps me ?[this is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1JVCV.png)

Comment: What is the URL you trying to use and have you done the thing they say you should do to debug it?

Comment: i used url for a web page in my website, the url is working fine,   when i used their debugger they told me it is invalid  and the status code is 404 ! , i don't know how

Comment: If Facebook says it return status code 404 it means that your server returns status code 404. We have no idea why your server does that.